# Use many to many relationship for all models

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, laravel, polymorphism

What are the disadvantages of implementing many to many relationships for all models? I think it would be easy to manage if something that requires it happened in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select info from db you need to make joins, which slows down your app.